# Auto Number Field Format

Tags: auto-number

I want to make an Auto Number Display Format field that start counting from 1 and not from 0.

means {1000}..

I'm getting an error when doing it on the auto number field..

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the format {0000}, but right below select the starting number to be 1
See related article for specifics

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019PmlQAE

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!